# Qt Squared Radio Button

Tags: qt, radio-button

I want to create a squared radio button, with the text inside the button. Is that possible? I think the button shape could be  changed trough css, but what about the text?

Any hint?

Comment: Might that not be easier achieved through a customized regular button and some radio-button-logic?

Comment: Like a QPushButton? Yes It could be..

Comment: Yeah, exactly. Might be an easier option.

Comment: What do you mean? Do you what Push Buttons to behave like Radio Buttons or do you want simply change Radio Button shape?

Comment: @besworland I want to change the shape of the radiobutton. I want the shape of the QPushButton and the behaviour of the QRadioButton

Comment: Then just use a QPushButton and write some simple code for QRadioButton-like behavior. That should not be all that difficult.

Comment: + to Bart! You have a property from QAbstractButtom that is called checkable. This property holds whether the button is checkable. By default, the button is not checkable. So set it to true.

Comment: ok thanks both of you. @Bart If you update your comment in an answer  I will glad to accept your answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than trying to deform a QRadioButton into something which visually resembles a QPushButton, I would simply use a QPushButton with some custom logic.

You won't have to worry about the visual aspect then, while the logic itself is not all that hard to write.

As stated by @besworland, QPushButton inherits from QAbstractButton, which already has the option to be checkable or not. You can set this via [`setCheckable(bool)`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractbutton.html#checkable-prop).

To mimic the "exclusive" behaviour of a set of QRadioButtons, you can add your buttons to a QButtonGroup and make it an exclusive one. As stated in [the documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qbuttongroup.html) *"An exclusive button group switches off all checkable (toggle) buttons except the one that was clicked."* You can use a QButtonGroup's [`setExclusive(bool)`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qbuttongroup.html#exclusive-prop) method for that.

In any case, I would consider those easier options than transforming a QRadioButton to fit your needs.

Comment: ok.. thank you. Asking to the Qt Forum somebody tell me to put the QPushButton inside the a QButtonGroup in order to let it mutually exclusive!! Could you update your answer?

Comment: Ah yeah, forgot about that one. True. Set it to exclusive and you should be good to go. I'll update.